# MySQL advanced sub query repetition

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm writing some reasonably complex queries for reporting for an app I am developing. I could probably achieve all of the following through using higher level PHP, but obviously I would like to get it all done with MySQL which will obviously simplify things greatly.

The report I need is a typical sales report type query, which will list a list of people, and some relevant totals relating to them. The only minor difference is that this system relates to freight/haulage, so the "sales people" are actually lorry drivers, and the "sales" are individual consignments. Also, consignments are only linked/tied to their respective driver through the creation of "routes", which record who delivers/collects what on a specific day.

Naturally, I could use an INNER JOIN to get a list of each driver, with all of the consignments they have delivered/collected, and SUM the revenue made off these. The problem comes however, when I need to show both a column for total **delivery revenue** and **collection revenue**. These figures can come from a *consignments* table, which lists every consignment. Each consignment can have a flag (ENUM "D","C") which donates whether it is a delivery or collection. This can almost be ascertained easily through using sub queries but still, there will be a lot of repetition.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT pr.driver_callsign, d.first_name, d.last_name, sum(pc.revenue) AS total_revenue
FROM pallet_routes AS pr
INNER JOIN drivers AS d ON d.driver_callsign = pr.driver_callsign
INNER JOIN pallet_consignments AS pc ON pc.route_id = pr.route_id
GROUP BY pr.driver_callsign
ORDER BY d.driver_callsign ASC
```

This obviously returns a list of each driver, with the total amount of revenue made from all consignments they have tied to them.

What would be the most efficient way to further split this `revenue` SUM field up to show a `SUM(revenue) WHERE type = "C"` and `SUM(revenue) WHERE type="D"`? Subqueries? UNION?

It may also be worth mentioning that the end query will be narrowed down to a date range. So for example there will be a `WHERE date BETWEEN x AND y` put against the `pallet_routes` table.

Any advice would be greatfully received. Please do ask if you want me to elaborate more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where your column `type` is, but if it's on `pallet_consignments`, you can try the following:

```
SELECT pr.driver_callsign, d.first_name, d.last_name, 
SUM(IF(pc.`type` = 'C', pc.revenue, 0)) collection_revenue,
SUM(IF(pc.`type` = 'D', pc.revenue, 0)) delivery_revenue
FROM pallet_routes AS pr
INNER JOIN drivers AS d ON d.driver_callsign = pr.driver_callsign
INNER JOIN pallet_consignments AS pc ON pc.route_id = pr.route_id
GROUP BY pr.driver_callsign
ORDER BY d.driver_callsign ASC
```

Otherwise, please mention where the column `type` is.

Comment: Hey Shef thanks for your time. Something like this would work in theory, I agree, but the MySQL interpreter doesnt like it and reports:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(IF(pc.`type` = 'D', pc.revenue, 0)) as delivery_revenue
FROM pallet_routes ' at line 3`

Comment: @George: Forgot a comma on the previous SUM! Try the updated query.

Comment: Shef, thanks for the reply! The updated query works perfectly, thanks very much! It didn't even cross my mind I could use an IF like that to achieve those results!

Comment: @George: You are welcome! That's why learning is part of our dictionaries! :) This query will do beautifully over any other type, and you can add a where or any other clause you like to it.